# Why do I need to start my wordpress permalink with "/index.php"?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have a relatively new wordpress installation on http://tallytree.com. I tried to change permalink today to make it nicer. However when I use

```
/%postname%/
```

as permalink and applied. Wordpress wrote this to .htaccess in the root of my blog:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now when I click on a post header on my blog I get an apache 404 error. I went ahead and changed the permalink to this custom structure:

```
/index.php/%postname%/
```

Now it works. But my URLs have an **index.php** in them for example:
http://tallytree.com/index.php/comparing-a-few-force-directed-layout-implimentations/

How can I setup the permalink so that index.php does not have to be in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the custom structure in Wordpress' Permalinks page to: /%category%/%postname%/

Wordpress should write this to the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

index.php will not show up in the url. If this works, you can then change the custom structure to /%postname%/